# Allergy desensitization: what is the mechanism? Could it happen with other immune responses?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, immunity, allergies

Allergy is a type of immune response against an otherwise harmless substance. If I understand it well, the aim of allergy immunotherapy is not to stimulate an immune response like the immunotherapy for for other diseases, but to progressively reduce it by controlled exposition to the antigen. Is the mechanism understood? Could the repeated long-term exposition to an antigen reduce other types of immune responses (to virus or bacteria for example?)